# SQL Query in Crystal Reports does not function properly

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, sql-server-express

Using Microsoft SQL Server Express

I'm fairly new to crystal reports and am trying to generate a report that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/euH2F.jpg

Is it possible to create an SQL query which has these entries as some sort of array or struct result? I've got, for example, a query that gives the Average Completion Days for a High Priority task, and it looks like this:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(d,"OPENDATE","CLSDDATE")*1.0) AS AvgCompletionDaysHighFromLastFullMonth
FROM "TRACKIT_DATA2"."TrackItApp_1"."vTASKS_BROWSE"
WHERE "PRIORITY" = 'High - 1 Day' 
AND DATEPART(m,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(m, {?reportingDate}) /*these next two lines specify closed tickets in the last month*/
AND DATEPART(yyyy,"CLSDDATE") = DATEPART(yyyy, {?reportingDate})
```

Now, I think I can create a query that creates each and every cell in that spreadsheet, but I don't know how to create a table of those results that could be accessed by that report. How can I "return a struct" of these queries that I can then use the "." operator (from C-like languages) to pick out for use in my report? I need to construct a query that combines all the individual queries I'm going to create.

Comment: are table names and where conditions same for all columns?

Comment: @Siva, the table names will be all the same, but where conditions will vary. For example, avgcompletiondaysLow will have 'where priority = 'low - 3 days''

Comment: one option that comes into my mind is to create one huge query that has many sub queries joined and which gives the output as all columns you required and use that query in crystal report... Which I think will be tedious and complex... One more option that I would suggest is to create as many views as your fields and join those views internally in crystal reports and generate the report.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "views?"

Comment: Ha! brain fart. Thanks for the help!